# Forwarding sequence

Tags: python

I wrote a simple class implementing the `collections.Sequence` interface, that forwards calls to its items to member functions of its items.

I'm requesting a review of the following code snippet.

```
import collections

class ForwardSequence(collections.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(ForwardSequence, self).__init__()
        self._sequence = tuple(*args)
        self._get = kw.pop('get', None)
        self._set = kw.pop('set', None)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._sequence)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            indices = item.indices(len(self))
            return [self[i] for i in range(*indices)]
        return self._get(self._sequence[item])

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        items = self._sequence[item]
        if not isinstance(items, collections.Sequence):
            items = (items,)
        for i in items:
            self._set(i, value)
```

E.g.

```
class Command(object):
    def query(self):
        # send and return query string.

    def write(self, value):
        #send write string.

class Controller(object):
    '''A simple temperature controller.'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.temperature = ForwardSequence(
            (Command() for _ in range(10)),
            get=lambda x: x.query(),
            set=lambda x, v: x.write(v)
        )

ctrl = Controller()

# calls the query method of the first 5 Commands and returns it's results
print ctrl.temperature[0:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections

class ForwardSequence(collections.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(ForwardSequence, self).__init__()
        self._sequence = tuple(*args)
```

A tuple only takes on argument, why are you passing a variable number of arguments?

```
        self._get = kw.pop('get', None)
        self._set = kw.pop('set', None)
```

Why don't you use keyword arguments instead of `**kw`? As it stands you are asking for trouble by ignoring any arguments that aren't there. Also, do you really want to allow the user to avoid specifying `get` and `set`. It seems to me those will always need to be defined.

```
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._sequence)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            indices = item.indices(len(self))
            return [self[i] for i in range(*indices)]
```

I'd suggest

```
return map(self._get, self_sequence[item])
```

That should offload some of the work onto the underlying sequence.

```
        return self._get(self._sequence[item])

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        items = self._sequence[item]
        if not isinstance(items, collections.Sequence):
            items = (items,)
```

I suggest checking `isinstance(item, slice)` instead of this. As it stands, it has confusing behaviour of sequence contains sequences. I'd also just call `self._set(item, value)`, as you aren't saving anything by storing the item in a one-length tuple

```
        for i in items:
            self._set(i, value)
```

I'm not sure I like the class's interface. It seems to be doing something more complex while masquerading as a list. This seems problematic to me. But I'd have to see more about how you use to know for certain.